# Will two-party garbled-circuit based protocol have any security issue when inputs are from multiple parties?

Tags: multiparty-computation, oblivious-transfer, garbled-circuits

If the inputs for a garbled circuit are from multiple parties, can parties (not garbler, not evaluator) obtain the labels corresponding to its input from the garbler via oblivious transfer then send the labels to the evaluator? Will this have any security issue?

Comment: Whether this idea is secure or not will depend on what security means in your context. Are the parties semi-honest? How many adversaries are there? Can a subset of the parties collude?